# How to fill the table with statuses for every day

Tags: postgresql

I have a table with the following structure:

| lead_id (integer) | created_at (timestapm) | pipeline (varchar(255)) | status (varchar(255)) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-12-28 12:25:43.000000 | Pip1 | Stat1 |
| 1 | 2021-12-28 15:40:18.000000 | Pip1 | Stat2 |
| 1 | 2022-01-01 13:25:12.000000 | Pip1 | Stat3 |
| 2 | 2022-01-01 12:30:00.000000 | Pip1 | Stat1 |
| 2 | 2022-01-02 17:40:28.000000 | Pip2 | Stat3 |
| 2 | 2022-01-04 12:25:11.000000 | Pip1 |  |

Scrip for create this table:

```
    CREATE TABLE deal_statuses(lead_id integer,
                created_at timestamp,
                pipeline varchar(255),
                status varchar(255)
    );
    
    INSERT INTO deal_statuses VALUES (1, '2021-12-28 12:25:43.000000', 'Pip1', 'Stat1'),
                                      (1, '2021-12-28 15:40:18.000000', 'Pip1', 'Stat2'),
                                      (1, '2022-01-01 13:25:12.000000', 'Pip1', 'Stat3'),
                                      (2, '2022-01-01 12:30:00.000000', 'Pip1', 'Stat1'),
                                      (2, '2022-01-02 17:40:28.000000', 'Pip2', 'Stat3'),
                                      (2, '2022-01-04 12:25:11.000000', 'Pip1', '');
```

I need to end up with a table or view containing current pipelines and statuses for each date for each lead_id.

Expected result (NOW() = 06.01.2022):

| lead_id | date | Pipeline | Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-12-28 | Pip1 | Stat2 |
| 1 | 2021-12-29 | Pip1 | Stat2 |
| 1 | 2021-12-30 | Pip1 | Stat2 |
| 1 | 2021-12-31 | Pip1 | Stat2 |
| 1 | 2022-01-01 | Pip1 | Stat3 |
| 1 | 2022-01-02 | Pip1 | Stat3 |
| 1 | 2022-01-03 | Pip1 | Stat3 |
| 1 | 2022-01-04 | Pip1 | Stat3 |
| 1 | 2022-01-05 | Pip1 | Stat3 |
| 1 | 2022-01-06 | Pip1 | Stat3 |
| 2 | 2022-01-01 | Pip1 | Stat1 |
| 2 | 2022-01-02 | Pip2 | Stat3 |
| 2 | 2022-01-03 | Pip2 | Stat3 |
| 2 | 2022-01-04 | Pip1 |  |
| 2 | 2022-01-05 | Pip1 |  |
| 2 | 2022-01-06 | Pip1 |  |

Now i have this:

```
create or replace view deal_statuses_all_date_test

            (date,
             lead_id,
             pipeline,
             status)
AS

WITH unic_deal_statuses AS (SELECT DISTINCT deal_statuses.lead_id
                            FROM deal_statuses),

     _calendar AS (
         SELECT '2021-12-27'::date + n.n AS date

         FROM generate_series(1, ((SELECT date_part('day'::text, now() -
                                                                 '2021-12-27 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone::timestamp with time zone) AS date_part))::integer +
                                 30) n(n)
     ),

     other AS (
         SELECT DISTINCT c.date,
                         uds.lead_id
         FROM (SELECT *
               FROM _calendar) c,
              (SELECT *
               FROM unic_deal_statuses) uds
         WHERE c.date <= now()::date
         ORDER BY c.date DESC
     )
SELECT t.date,
       t.lead_id,
       first_value(t.pipeline) OVER (PARTITION BY t.gpr, t.lead_id) AS value, 
       first_value(t.status) OVER (PARTITION BY t.gpr, t.lead_id)   AS value1
FROM (SELECT o.date,
             o.lead_id,
             ds.pipeline,
             ds.status,
             sum(
             CASE
                 WHEN ds.pipeline IS NOT NULL THEN 1
                 ELSE 0
                 END) OVER (ORDER BY o.date) AS gpr
      FROM other o
               LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT deal_statuses.created_at,
                                          deal_statuses.lead_id,
                                          deal_statuses.pipeline,
                                          deal_statuses.status 

                          FROM deal_statuses
                          ORDER BY deal_statuses.created_at DESC) ds
                         on o.lead_id = ds.lead_id) t

ORDER BY t.date DESC;
```

This code returns all records by lead_id for each date:

| lead_id | date | Pipeline | Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-12-28 | Pip1 | Stat1 |
| 1 | 2021-12-28 | Pip1 | Stat2 |
| 1 | 2021-12-28 | Pip1 | Stat3 |
| 2 | 2021-12-28 | Pip1 | Stat1 |
| 2 | 2021-12-28 | Pip2 | Stat3 |
| 2 | 2021-12-28 | Pip1 |  |
| ---- | ---------- | ---- | ----- |
| 1 | 2022-01-06 | Pip1 | Stat1 |
| 1 | 2022-01-06 | Pip1 | Stat2 |
| 1 | 2022-01-06 | Pip1 | Stat3 |
| 2 | 2022-01-06 | Pip1 | Stat1 |
| 2 | 2022-01-06 | Pip2 | Stat3 |
| 2 | 2022-01-06 | Pip1 |  |

I am new to postgres and this site.
I hope I was able to describe the problem in sufficient detail and clearly.

Comment: Add script for create table, sample data and expected result. `2021-12-29` does not appear in the record set. Where does it come from ?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Philippe.
Record 12/29/2021 is not in the source table. All dates are supposed to be taken from the calendar table.

Perhaps my approach to solving the problem was initially incorrect.

Perhaps you have an idea of ​​what it might look like. I do not really need a ready-made solution, at least a direction for further reflection on the problem.

Comment: Added a script to create table and populate it with data.
I presented the expected result in the table Example. Renamed to Expected result.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand your business logic detailly, but I wrote a sample query for you. My query has two main tables, one of the tables returns a date list, the second table returns grouping data of the `deal_statuses` table.
My sample query:

```
with 
date_tables as 
(
    select 
        t1.generate_series::date as dates 
    from 
        (
            SELECT * from generate_series(now()::date - 30, now()::date, '1 day')  
        ) t1 
), 
d_statuses as 
( 
    select distinct 
        t2.lead_id, 
        t2.created_date, 
        first_value(t2.pipeline) over (partition by t2.lead_id, t2.created_date) as pipeline, 
        first_value(t2.status) over(partition by t2.lead_id, t2.created_date) as status 
    from (
        select 
            lead_id,
            (created_at)::date as created_date, 
            pipeline,
            status 
        from deal_statuses
    ) t2 
    order by t2.lead_id 
)
select a2.lead_id, a1.dates, a2.pipeline, a2.status from date_tables a1 
inner join d_statuses a2 on a1.dates = a2.created_date
```

if when you will use `inner join` you can gets this result:

```
lead_id     dates       pipeline    status
---------------------------------------------
1           2022-03-02  Pip1        Stat1
1           2022-03-05  Pip1        Stat2
1           2022-03-11  Pip1        Stat3
2           2022-03-18  Pip1        Stat1
2           2022-03-26  Pip2        Stat3
2           2022-03-27  Pip1
```

if when you will use `left join` you can gets this result:

```
lead_id     dates       pipeline    status
--------------------------------------------
            2022-02-25  
            2022-02-26  
            2022-02-27  
            2022-02-28  
            2022-03-01  
1           2022-03-02  Pip1        Stat1
            2022-03-03  
            2022-03-04  
1           2022-03-05  Pip1        Stat2
            2022-03-06  
            2022-03-07  
            2022-03-08  
            2022-03-09  
            2022-03-10  
1           2022-03-11  Pip1        Stat3
            2022-03-12  
            2022-03-13  
            2022-03-14  
            2022-03-15  
            2022-03-16  
            2022-03-17  
2           2022-03-18  Pip1        Stat1
            2022-03-19  
            2022-03-20  
            2022-03-21  
            2022-03-22  
            2022-03-23  
            2022-03-24  
            2022-03-25  
2           2022-03-26  Pip2        Stat3
2           2022-03-27  Pip1
```